# How do people make custom Pokemon for Pokemon Sword & Shield?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

An advertisement I saw for custom Pokemon for Pokemon Sword & Shield:

[image: Any Custom Shiny 6IV Pokemon for Sword & Shield]

Some people are selling custom Pokemon for Pokemon Sword & Shield.

Most of the ads have similar promises to this:

> Get any 6 custom made Pokemon for Sword and Shield!
>
> ANY legal Level, Nickname, Shiny/Non-Shiny, Nature, Hold items, Ability, 6IVs, EVs for stats, Trainer Name, Trainer ID No., Trainer Secret ID- trade me a pokemon first if you would like me to tell you your secret ID, Moves
>
> Anything OT or pokeball related simply type at the bottom I will be checking for that.
>
> You MUST have a Nintendo Switch Online Membership in order for us to trade.
>
> During purchase PLEASE message me your trainer name and a time when you're available to trade (I am on central time), we will exchange the 4 digit code then.

My question is: **How do they make such custom pokemon?**

Are they just breeding, farming money, buying vitamins etc etc etc legitimately?

Or are they using some kind of homebrew cheating system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some of the fields that they are saying can be set in this transaction, they are using a 3rd party program to generate the new pokemon.

For instance, trainer name/trainer ID cannot be set easily (and trainer ID is random). For them to be able to set these to whatever you choose, it would take an unreasonable amount of time restarting a game to get the correct combination.

Also, to ensure the perfect combination of nature, IVs (set at time of catch, not to be confused with EVs), etc. of a *shiny* pokemon of any variety of your choosing would take an immense amount of time and luck.

As is seen on your second posting, the seller usually have some sort of "disclaimer" saying they will provide any *legal* pokemon (no impossible movesets, no lvl 1 legendary, etc.), presumably to avoid detection of anti-cheating measures during & after trade.

Comment: I found out they are using PKHeX (a save editor) in Homebrew

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the same tool also used in previous generations of pokemon games for the same purpose. I knew they existed, but couldn't recall the names when writing up the answer. I don't follow that side of the pokemon scene. :)

Comment: Nature can be changed with Mints, and IVs can be maxed with Bottle Caps (requires level 100, and beating the main game.  Normal Bottle Caps let you max 1 stat, Gold Bottle Caps will max all 6) - but you're right about the trainer details etc

Answer (score 1):

They are using the older unpatched Switch with PKHeX in order to edit pokemon.

It is legitimate in the sense that you can use it in online ranked battles as the pokemon themselves are legal and practically impossible to tell that it has been hacked if done correctly.

Also, in addition to what the parameters you have mentioned, it is also possible to edit how you met the pokemon, on what date, pokeball captured in and ribbons, which further boosts the legitimacy.